# Use Python ftplib ftp.dir() or ftp.retrlines('LIST') to return only files containing a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I am accessing a government website from Python 3.6 like this:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP("somedepartment.gov")
ftp.login()
>>> '230 Anonymous access granted, restrictions apply'

filepath = "/path/to/ftp/folder/"
ftp.cwd(filepath)
>>> '250 CWD command successful'
```

Then, I go to list the contents of the directory, both `ftp.dir()` or `ftp.retrlines('LIST')` seem to have the same effect, listing out an enormous directory into the Jupyter output. I tried to assign the output of these commands to a variable but it contains nothing, which is anyway in line with the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.dir). I just wanted to find the names of a few files containing a certain string, not a huge list. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there's no other way, than retrieving list of all files and filtering them locally.

See [Python: How to get list of file and use wildcard in FTP directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43670948/850848)

---

But many servers support non-standard/proprietary filtering of the listing.

If you are lucky and your FTP server do support this, you can use a file mask to retrieve only a subset of files. In your case the mask would be a simple `*` pattern, which is supported by most major FTP servers.

```
ftp.retrlines('LIST *string*')
```

---

For a partial list of supported patterns of common FTP servers, see my answer to [FTP directory partial listing with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282753/850848#28187442).

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Read under the tab 'ftp', "a well-established protocol for conducting file operations (such as transferring files) over a TCP-based network such as the Internet" which does not sound like just Python, so might look into its docs if I need something else.